# fastAPI for azure cosmos db: how to make conditional sql queries

Tags: python, fastapi, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm making a fastAPI to retrieve some data from Azure Cosmos DB in python.

Basically my query asks 4 user inputs, but as you see in my code below each value can be None. How can I make this sql query dynamic so that even though there are only 2 or  user inputs, for example, the Cosmos DB spits out the result?

```
@app.get("/items/")
async def db_queries(a: Union[str, None] = None, b: Union[str, None] = None,
c: Union[str, None] = None, d: Union[str, None] = None)
return container.query_items(query='SELECT * FROM r WHERE r.a=@name AND r.b=@area AND r.c>=@from AND r.d<=@till',
    parameters=[{'name':'@name','value':a},
                {'name':'@area','value':b},
                {'name':'@from','value':c},
                {'name':'@till','value':d}], enable_cross_partition_query=True)
```

Comment: Compose your query string programmatically by first determining the terms that should be present, then ANDing them together (`' AND '.join(terms)`) and including the present parameters?

Comment: Many thanks. I've got inspired by your comment, although concise.